# Consulta em dois campos de uma tabela

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, pessoal 
Utilizo duas tabelas providencia e ocorrência - sendo que tenho 1 ocorrência para N providencias. Preciso realizar uma consulta de registro que traga quantas providencias tem a ocorrência.

Segue a imagem da minha base, fica mas fácil para entender [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso realizar uma consultar que traga minhas Minhas providencias que estão vinculadas para a ocorrência que vou digitar na pesquisa.

Comment: Coloque a estrutura e popule de forma simples: http://lorefnon.me/plain-text-table/

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários jeitos de efetuar essa busca, "igualdade de chave" e "inner join".

```
//inner join
select count(providencia.cod_provid) from providencia inner join ocorrencia on occorencia.cod_ocorrencia = providencia.cod_ocorrencia;
// igualdade de chaves
select count(cod_provid) from providencia, ocorrencia where providencia.cod_ocorrencia = ocorrencia.cod_ocorrencia
```

Provavelmente o inner join daria mais certo.

Comment: Estou utilizando o banco em access para teste, ao executar o modulo sql informa que esta com falha na expressão inner join ....

Comment: estava com um erro de sintaxe no código, `on occorencia.cod_ocorrencia == providencia.cod_ocorrencia` mas já consertei, o correto é `on occorencia.cod_ocorrencia = providencia.cod_ocorrencia`, verifica os nomes dos campos tbm.

Comment: Brumazzi eu te agradeço, mas esse comando só trás o último registro da tabela e não todas as providencias da tabela de ocorrência. Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Comment: O código realmente deve retornar um valor, assim como o que você pediu, "Preciso realizar uma consulta de registro que traga quantas providencias tem a ocorrencia." o código conta quantas providencias existem e retorna, se quiser o retorno das providencias substitua `count(providencia.cod_provid)` por `providencia.cod_provid`, isso irá retornar os códigos das providencias.

Comment: Vou te dá exemplo da imagem - Meu Cod_ocorrencia 0000002 gerou dois cod_provid 00002 e 00003. Preciso gerar uma consulta que na tela de pesquisa ao digitar o cod_ocorrencia informe que tem 2 registros para essa providencia.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizaria:

Se você quiser buscar os dados das providências

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ocorrencia o
INNER JOIN providencia p ON (o.cod_ocorrencia = p.cod_ocorrencia)
WHERE o.cod_ocorrencia = 1;
```

Se você quiser buscar a quantidade de providências para aquela ocorrencia

```
SELECT count(p.cod_providencia)
FROM ocorrencia o
INNER JOIN providencia p ON (o.cod_ocorrencia = p.cod_ocorrencia)
WHERE o.cod_ocorrencia = 1;
```

**Substitua 1 pelo id da ocorrencia que você está buscando.**

Comment: Seu código ocorre erro de sintaxe

Comment: Teria como ser mais especifica? Talvez seja o nome de alguma coluna? Qual das duas queries? Ambas?

Comment: achei onde estava, a coluna que estava no clausula where estava ambigua. Então o banco não sabia em qual tabela buscar, na ocorrencia ou providencia. Modifiquei a query e testei aqui, testa de novo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o COUNT() juntamente com o GROUP BY para retornar. No seu caso, seria algo como:

```
SELECT
   COD_OCORRENCIA,
   COUNT(COD_PROVID) AS TOTAL_PROVID
FROM
   ocorrencia,
   providencia
WHERE
   ocorrencia.COD_OCORRENCIA = providencia.COD_OCORRENCIA
GROUP BY COD_OCORRENCIA
```

Dessa forma, a consulta retornará para cada ocorrencia o total de providencias (count) quando houver relação entre elas, agrupando pelo COD_OCORRENCIA.